# How can I calculate the width of my image properly so that the side buttons will align evenly?

Tags: javascript, css

So I have this image gallery with a next arrow button and a previous arrow button. I wrote this calculation to get the (window width - image width) / 2 in order to make each button exactly the same distance. However, the buttons aren't aligning properly even though the html shows that they are exactly the same distance in px's.

Here are some images of what I mean

Here is the image size

[image]

The html clearly shows each button with the exact px spacing

[image]

And see how the next button (right button) isn't properly aligned with the image?

[image]

Here is the code I wrote to calculate this

```js
let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
let imgWidth = this.width;
let calcImgToEdge = (windowWidth - imgWidth) / 2;
```

Here is the CSS for the Buttons

```css
.img-btns {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #111111;
    position: fixed;
    top: 48vh;
    z-index: 500;
    color: var(--white);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Here is the window CSS

```
.img-window {
width: 100vw;
height:100vh;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 100;
cursor: pointer;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

Then the popup image CSS

```
.popup-img {
max-height: 80vh;
max-width: 80vw;
z-index: 200; 
 }
```

So basically calculation takes the entire window's width and subtracts the images width, then divides that by 2. I don't see how the buttons aren't perfectly aligned even though my calculation evens everything out?

Comment: Can you please put your code in snippet?

Comment: Please share the html code also, so that the issue can be better understood. Thanks.

Comment: it's not coded in html, it's created with javascript so the picture above shows the html code

Comment: please add the full javascript to make it a working example

Comment: How are you going to use this, is this a popup? I'm thinking this could be done easier with css but you could start with explaning the first :)

Comment: it's an image gallery and that image is a popup image, and the arrows let me switch to the next images. The right button is literally off by like 10px so that's all I'm trying to figure out how to make it centered with the left button

Answer (score 0):

If you put the buttons either side of `.img-window`, then wrap them all in a parent div (If you haven't already), set the buttons to `position: absolute` and the parent to:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

It should work with any sized image. Without seeing the rest of the HTML it's hard to tell but hopefully it's what you're after.

Comment: the image is just used to show how the arrows aren't aligned, but ideally, they would both be around 100px away from the picture on each side, so I wouldn't want them to be inside the same div. Just like a typical image gallery where you have the arrows a little out on the sides of the image

Comment: You could still have them on the same side as they are if you wrap just the buttons in a parent div, set the div to `width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex;  align-items: center; justify-content: center;`. Again, without seeing more code I'm not 100% sure but, give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Let's start here. If you post your full js I can help you figure this out.

```css
.gallery-popup {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.gallery-popup {
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
}

.gallery-popup__button {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #111111;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 500;
  color: var(--white);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-popup">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" alt="" class="gallery-popup__img">
  
  <a href="#0" class="gallery-popup__button gallery-popup__button-prev"><</a>
  <a href="#0" class="gallery-popup__button gallery-popup__button-next">></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

At first if you ask image to be on fullscreen you just have to add `position:fixed` and `top:50%` and this will work.At second if the height of the image is known you can divide by 2 this height and add again `position:fixed` and `top:(divided value in pixels)`.At last you just can get the height of the div (img-window) and add buttons below the image after that align them by CSS positioning (again you can use 50% of height).

Comment: can you write that in code? I'm not sure what you're saying